# Merging two files with a specific character through Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, merge, multiple-columns

**Input: file1**

```
0    1    2    
ch1  SLC  d4p   
ch1  WEK  d20i  
ch2  XLW  k13q   
ch2  PCX  w2p    
ch3  KCE  p102x  
ch3  KXS  m7t
```

**Input: file2**

```
0    1
KKC  lsdkjlcjskndv
SLC  slkdmcokwem
PCX  owkemofkwne
KXS  oikmokm
KBK  pwekjclwmef
OOO  lkmcoinwoien
```

**Expected output: file1#**

```
0    1    2     3
ch1  SLC  d4p   slkdmcokwem
ch1  WEK  d20i  NaN
ch2  XLW  k13q  NaN
ch2  PCX  w2p   owkemofkwne
ch3  KCE  p102x NaN
ch3  KXS  m7t   oikmokm
```

**Result**

```
0    1    2     3
ch1  SLC  d4p   NaN
ch1  WEK  d20i  NaN
ch2  XLW  k13q  NaN
ch2  PCX  w2p   NaN
ch3  KCE  p102x NaN
ch3  KXS  m7t   NaN
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

lines_1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
lines_2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

merge_two_files = pd.merge(left=lines_1, right=lines_2, on=[1], how='left')
merge_two_files.columns = range(len(merge_two_files.columns))
```

I wanna get the 'Expected output: file1#', but the result is just like 'Result' with this code. I'm sorry but is there any suggestions you have?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use a `left_on` and `right_on` in your [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) statement.  Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: ["ch1", "ch1", "ch2", "ch2", "ch3", "ch3"],
        1: ["SLC", "WEK", "XLW", "PCX", "KCE", "KXS"],
        2: ["d4p", "d20i", "k13q", "w2p", "p102x", "m7t"]
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: ["KKC", "SLC", "PCX", "KXS", "KBK", "OOO"],
        1: ["lsdkjlcjskndv", "slkdmcokwem", "owkemofkwne", "oikmokm", "pwekjclwmef", "lkmcoinwoien"]
    }
)

merged = pd.merge(
    left = df1, 
    right = df2, 
    left_on = 1, 
    right_on = 0, 
    how = 'left'
)
merged.head()

'''
Result:
     1  0_x  1_x      2  0_y          1_y
0  SLC  ch1  SLC    d4p  SLC  slkdmcokwem
1  WEK  ch1  WEK   d20i  NaN          NaN
2  XLW  ch2  XLW   k13q  NaN          NaN
3  PCX  ch2  PCX    w2p  PCX  owkemofkwne
4  KCE  ch3  KCE  p102x  NaN          NaN


'''
```

To be clear, what's happening here is that you're merging the two data frames on column 1, which are different values in the two dataframes. You actually want to merge on column `1` in the first dataframe, and column `0` in the second dataframe.

Comment: 0 1 2 3 4 5\n   SLC  ch1  SLC  d4p  SLC  slkdmcokwem ---> I'm so sorry but it's the form of your answer.

Comment: Edited with a more code-complete example. The output columns are slightly different than what you want, but those should probably be renamed upstream of this merge anyways. Then you could just merge on the column name, rather than the integer.